# Botão para inserir registos na BD

Tags: c#, sql, .net, visual-studio

Estou a realizar um projeto para a minha PAP que consiste na criação de uma Base de Dados para uma empresa.

No entanto, decidi colocar um botão para adicionar registos e quando clico para adicionar, aparece o seguinte erro:

> **Falha ao converter o valor do parâmetro de Bitmap para Byte[]**.

```
 SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("insert into Utilizador(IDuser, Nome, Localidade, DataDeNascimento, Idade, Email, Login, Senha,
 Telefone, TelefoneEE, Perfil, Imagem) values (@IDuser, @Nome, @Localidade, @DatadeNascimento, @Idade, @Email, @Login, @Senha, @Telefone, @TelefoneEE, @Perfil, @Imagem", sql);
              command.Parameters.Add("@IDuser", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = iDuserTextBox.Text;
              command.Parameters.Add("@Nome", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = nomeTextBox.Text;
              command.Parameters.Add("@Localidade", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = localidadeTextBox.Text;
              command.Parameters.Add("@DataDeNascimento", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dataDeNascimentoDateTimePicker.Value;
              command.Parameters.Add("@Idade", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = idadeTextBox.Text;
              command.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = emailTextBox.Text;
              command.Parameters.Add("@Login", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = loginTextBox.Text;
              command.Parameters.Add("@Senha", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = senhaTextBox.Text;
              command.Parameters.Add("@Telefone", SqlDbType.Char).Value = telefoneTextBox.Text;
              command.Parameters.Add("@TelefoneEE", SqlDbType.Char).Value = telefoneEETextBox.Text;
              command.Parameters.Add("@Imagem", SqlDbType.Image).Value = imagemPictureBox.Image;
              command.Parameters.Add("@Perfil", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = perfilTextBox.Text;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Use um [`ImageConverter`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imageconverter?view=netframework-4.8) ou use um [`MemoryStream`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream?view=netframework-4.8)